# No payload field in Messages.get response

Tags: php, gmail-api

I'm pretty new to the gmail api. I'm trying to write a script that can access my inbox with php. I'm able to successfully make calls to the api but when I use the get method, I don't receive any payload in the response.

```
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

$user = 'me';
$messages = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($user,["q"=>"is:unread"]);

foreach($messages as $message)
{
  print "\nMessage Id: " . $message->id . "\n";
  $messageObject = $service->users_messages->get($user,$message->id,["format"=>"full"]);
  print json_encode($messageObject);
}
```

One of my responses, for reference, is as follows:

```
Message Id: 15af8a0461fe2b11
{"historyId":"1028","id":"15af8a0461fe2b11","internalDate":"1490229938000","labelIds":["UNREAD","INBOX"],"raw":null,"sizeEstimate":4831,"snippet":"Hi Brian Get the official Gmail app The best features of Gmail are only available on your phone and tablet with the official Gmail app. Download the app or go to gmail.com on your computer or mobile","threadId":"15af8a0461fe2b11"}
```

I've read on other stack overflow threads and the api documentation that I should be able to access the MessagePart object with $messageObject->getPayload() but as the response doesn't even have a payload field, it returns null.

Any advice?

**Edit:**
All other messages I attempt to retrieve have a similar response.

When I try to send an email to myself with the following

```
$message_object = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
$encoded_message = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode("From: 'Brian Z'  
<brian@mydomain.example>
Subject: Test Message
To: 'Brian Z' <brian@mydomain.example>
Test Message"), '+/', '-_'), '=');
$message_object->setRaw($encoded_message);
$test = $service->users_messages->send($user, $message_object);
print json_encode($test);
```

I receive the following output

```
{"historyId":null,"id":"15b03f64b7261425","internalDate":null,"labelIds":["UNREAD","SENT","INBOX"],"raw":null,"sizeEstimate":null,"snippet":null,"threadId":"15b03f64b7261425"}
```

Comment: Is the result the same for other messages? Do you get the same result if you e.g. send a message to yourself?

Comment: The other messages have a similar result. I'll edit the original post to show the result of what you asked

Comment: Interesting. That's very odd. Could you send a message to yourself with the regular Gmail client just to make sure?

Comment: The regular gmail client? Are you referring to the panel on the side? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send

Comment: I mean that you could try to send a regular mail to yourself and look if that has a payload, not send a message with the API.

Comment: Ah yeah, when I send myself emails and then try to get them with the get method, they return similar json objects (no payload). An interesting observation though: when I use the form on google's documentation to call the get method, the returned object actually has a payload. It just seems to be incomplete when I call the api through my script.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Maybe you've found a bug in the php client library?

Comment: I suppose I'll report it then and use a different language for the time being. Thanks a bunch for your time, Tholle :)